# what does python 3.6 subprocess.Popen().returncode of 100 means?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, ubuntu-18.04

My `subprocess.Popen()` function (see below) had returned a 100 `returncode`. What does this mean? I could not find a reference showing the meaning of 100. Can you explain to me? Thank you.

```
import subprocess

def call_subprocess_Popen( cmd, cwd=None ):
    ''' Execute a command in BASH. kwargs: "cmd" is a list.'''
    with subprocess.Popen( cmd, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, cwd=cwd,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, ) as result:
        for line in result.stdout:
            print( line, end='' )
    print( 'result.returncode' )
    print( 'result.args' )
    if result.returncode != 0:
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError( result.returncode, result.args )
    else:
        return True

def pkexec_apt_get_y_install( packages ):
    print( f'\nProcess {os.getpid()} {threading.current_thread()} pkexec apt_get_y_install ....' )
    cmd = [ 'pkexec', 'apt-get', '-y', 'install' ]
    cmd.extend( packages )
    print( f'cmd = {cmd}' )
    if call_subprocess_Popen( cmd ):
        return True
    else:
        return False

apps = [ 'synaptic', 'ubuntu-restricted-extra', 'apt-xapian-index' ]
pkexec_apt_get_y_install( apps )
```

Error Msg:

```
Process 5979 <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140069990864704)> pkexec apt_get_y_install ....
cmd = ['pkexec', 'apt-get', '-y', 'install', 'synaptic', 'ubuntu-restricted-extra', 'apt-xapian-index']
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
result.returncode
result.args
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/customiseUbuntu1804.py", line 223, in <module>
    main()
  File "~/customiseUbuntu1804.py", line 205, in main
    pkexec_apt_get_y_install( setup_apps )
  File "~/customiseUbuntu1804.py", line 76, in pkexec_apt_get_y_install
    if call_subprocess_Popen( cmd ):
  File "~/customiseUbuntu1804.py", line 47, in call_subprocess_Popen
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError( result.returncode, result.args )
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['pkexec', 'apt-get', '-y', 'install', 'synaptic', 'ubuntu-restricted-extra', 'apt-xapian-index']' returned non-zero exit status 100.
```

Comment: can you provide your source code?

Comment: @rusu_ro1 I have provided the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like you got your 100 returncode from apt-get install command :

```
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extra
```

Comment: How can I reconfigure my code to expose this error msg?

Comment: the best way is to check your last line form result.stdout

Comment: As you can see in the source code and Error Msg, `result.stdout` was printed. It's last printout was `Reading state information...` before `print( 'result.returncode' )` took over. The statement `E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extra` that you had mentioned did not appear. I noticed that it did appeared when the same command was submitted in the terminal. I wonder what is causing the discrepancy?

Comment: Finally found the missing link. By adding `for line in result.stderr: print( line, end='' )` right after `for line in result.stdout: print( line, end='')` in my source code, I discovered that the error statement `E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extra` was printed out. `subprocess.Popen().stderr` holds the error statement(s).

Comment: Also, needed to  include `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` as a kwargs of `subprocess.Popen()`, i.e. `subprocess.Popen( ......, stderr=subprocess.PIPE )`, for the above mentioned to work.

Answer (score 4):

The return code comes from your external command and it can mean anything.

**Example:**

*"test.py" Python code:*

```
import subprocess


def call_command():
    process = subprocess.Popen(["./test.sh"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = process.communicate()
    return out, err, process.returncode


output, err, ret_code = call_command()
print("OUT: {}".format(output))
print("ERROR: {}".format(err))
print("Return code: {}".format(ret_code))
```

*"test.sh" Shell script:*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "This shell script will return with 100 return code"
exit 100
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
OUT: b'This shell script will return with 100 return code\n'
ERROR: None
Return code: 100
```

It means you need to look for the answer in the external command which is called by python.

**NOTE:**

Perhaps you have https sources. You can try to install apt-transport-https before executing other `apt-get` command. Command: `apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https`

Comment: From what you say and my code as shown above, am I correct to understand that the code 100 is returned by `apt-get`? Is there a way to show what 100 means?